# is there any better pandas function then pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal for testing two dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

is there any better pandas function then pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal because i am facing two issues while comparing

1. if the data set is like this

   df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','mqr','sas','ho']})
   df2=pd.DataFrame({'m':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds'], 'n':['sdd','gbc','mqr','sas','ho']})

[image]
[image]

I will give this error

[image]

2. if the dataset is like this

   df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','mqr','sas','ho']})
   df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','sds','ss','sd'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','ho','mqr','sas']})

[image]
[image]

then I am getting this error

[image]

due to the order of rows which is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal is a very robust package that checks a lot of things, if you just want to check that the data they contain are equal (without regards to colnames, index or dtype etc.) it might be easier just to write a simple function to do it.

You will have to sort your values, then convert to a numpy array to get rid of the indices and column headers. Finally we can compare the arrays using `np.array_equal()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','mqr','sas','ho']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':['abc','pqr','sds','ss','sd'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','ho','mqr','sas']})

print(df1.equals(df2))
# False

def assert_equal_df(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.sort_values(df1.columns[0]).to_numpy()
    df2 = df2.sort_values(df2.columns[0]).to_numpy()
    
    return np.array_equal(df1, df2)

print(assert_equal_df(df1, df2))
# True
```